# JSoup how to know document.select() argument?

Tags: java, networking, web, jsoup, html

I'm a beginner with JSoup and I found a simple code in another question. With this code you can get some infos from a stackoverflow question (like the question, answerers, ecc...).

A part of that code is:

```
String question = document.select("#question .post-text").text();
```

I understand all the code but I can't understand how to get/know/find the string that should be put inside the `document.select()` brackets. In this case it's `"#question .post-text"`.

I ask this question because I think that for each website there's a different string...
So how can I get that `String`?

Comment: Try to read here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: It is CSS query. You can check how your HTML document looks like by using your browser, or better (in case of dynamically generated document by JavaScript print value of `document` - `System.out.println(document)` ) and decide which elements you want to select. Here is some basic tutorial http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to [Jsoup Try](http://try.jsoup.com) and use and understand what selection gives each string or data.

Give the whole page's html our grab html by fetch URL. 
Then from the Select CSS Query you can try various options.